# Measuring Running Time of Code Chunk in R After Running

Tags: r, performance

I know there are several functions (e.g. Sys.time) that can be used to measure the running time of a code chunk in R. However, that requires you to set up the commands before you run the chunk. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to measure the time a code chunk took to run *after* it has been run?

For example, let's say you want to run this:

```
dummy = rep(NA, 100000)
dummy[1] = 1
for(i in 2:length(dummy)){
   dummy[i] = dummy[i - 1] + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 5)
}
```

Is there a way that you would be able to ask R for how long it took to run this code chunk?

Comment: No, unless you have a good watch, perfect memory and a keen eye ;-)

Comment: @January just post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jupyter notebook, it has a function called nbextension that calculates execution time.

https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/execute_time/readme.html